How can I effectively isolate state in Jest?
I want to write my tests using GIVEN, WHEN, THEN. GIVEN sets the initial state (e.g. initializes instances), WHEN changes it (eg calls methods on those instances), THEN asserts the new state (e.g. asserts equality).
At first, I tried:
describe('GIVEN ...', () => {
  const instance = new MyClass();
  describe('WHEN ...', () => {
    instance.doSomething();
    test('THEN 1...', () => {
      // Assert
   });
    test('THEN 2...', () => {
      // Other assert
   });
  });

  describe('WHEN ...', () => {
    instance.doOtherThing();
    test('THEN 3...', () => {
      // Assert
   });
    test('THEN 4...', () => {
      // Other assert
   });
  });
});

Which doesn't work because describes are ran before tests, so THEN 3 and 4 have the state from doSomething.
I then tried:
describe('GIVEN ...', () => {
  let instance: MyClass;

  beforeEach(() => instance = new MyClass());

  // Tests same as above
});

Which doesn't work because again, the WHENs describes are ran before the beforeEach, so it errors with cannot read properties of undefined.
After that, I tried:

From the example above, I tried wrapping all usages of instance inside WHENs on beforeAll, but it doesn't seem to work either (cannot read properties of undefined), it looks like they are being ran before the parent's beforeEach. I can't use beforeEachs inside WHENs because that'd mutate the state for every test, causing duplicates.

From the first example, I tried manually instantiating the class on each WHEN. That works, but then the GIVEN does nothing at all, when it's supposed to set up the initial state.


Is there any feasible way I can do what I need?

They is a complete misuse of the test structure, the cases shouldn't be interdependent like that.

@jonrsharpe Thanks for the response. Do you think I'm misunderstanding the pattern or what alternatives would you suggest?
